# How do I make a label show up without a mouseover on leaflet polygons?

Tags: jquery, leaflet, tooltip, polygon, geojson

I'm trying to label my geojson polygons on my leaflet map. I understand that the [label plugin has been deprecated](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244457/leaflet-label-plugin-not-working) and I'm supposed to use tooltip instead. However, my tooltips only show up when I mouse over my polygons. I want them to just show on top of my polygons as plain labels, without that arrow thing-y on them. This is the code I have, but what it does is show my labels on mouseover. I just want them to show **without** any action having to be taken. How would I do this?

Included files:

```
<script src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="js/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="data/parcels-fifth.geojson"></script>
```

jquery:

```
    var map = L.map('map').setView([40.350632, -79.86776], 19); //set up map

    L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner-lite/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.{ext}', {
        attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 20,
        ext: 'png'
    }).addTo(map);

    var parcels = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("data/parcels-fifth.geojson",{
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.PROPERTYHOUSENUM__asmt + " " + feature.properties.PROPERTYADDRESS__asmt + "<br>" + feature.properties.USEDESC__asmt, { 'noHide': true });
        }
    }).addTo(map)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a own Label with a Div-Marker: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59422437/8283938

or you can add `permanent: true` to the tooltip: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tooltip-permanent

`layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.PROPERTYHOUSENUM__asmt + " " + feature.properties.PROPERTYADDRESS__asmt + "<br>" + feature.properties.USEDESC__asmt, { 'permanent': true });`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this code](https://plnkr.co/edit/4xmd4f2DKRWVUGAC?preview) to show label in polygon :

```
var eu = L.geoJSON(euCountries, {
    
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        
   // if (feature.geometry.type === "Polygon") {
            
            var bounds = layer.getBounds();
            // Get center of bounds
            var center = bounds.getCenter();
      //var center = layer.getBounds().getCenter();
            if(feature.properties.name=="russia")
            {
                alert(center)
            }
            layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.name, {permanent: true, direction: "center", className: "my-labels"});
            layer.on("click", function (e) {
                 layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
            });

     /* var marker =L.circleMarker(center, {color: '', radius:10,Title:20}).bindTooltip(feature.properties.name, {permanent: true, direction: "center", className: "my-labels"});
             map.addLayer(marker);*/
     // var polygonAndItsCenter = L.layerGroup([layer, marker]);
   // }
  },
});
eu.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.